# Service sequence - don't call first service again on next user click, if second one failed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Asking for your help. I am beginner with Angular + RxJS, please don't blame me if this is easy task.

Idea is to submit form in which are many input fields and one of those is image upload.
When user click on submit button, first it needs to call POST /attachments service with added file to get it's token. When this service returns attachment's token, then need to use it in final service call where I am sending all form data.

Special case is, if user submit form, first service response with attachment's token and second one fails, then when user click one more time on submit button, shouldn't call /attachments service again, but just use previously got attachment's token and call form's POST service.

Is it possible with using some of RxJS operators or other features?
I know I can get it working with some ugly logic all around in my app, but I want to make it also beautiful too.

There is my first version of code for submit function.

```
public submitForm(finalData) {
  const { attachment, ...data } = finalData;

  return this.http
    // at first get attachment's token
    .post('/attachments', attachment)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((attachmentToken) => {
        const formData = {
          data,
          attachment: attachmentToken
        };

        // submit form data
        return this.http.post('/submitformdata', formData)
      }),
    );
}
```

Comment: you can put both calls separately and disable submit button until user selects any attachment and attachment token is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the attachment token and request based on it :

```
attachmentToken: string;

public submitForm(finalData) {
  const { attachment, ...data } = finalData;
  return !this.attachmentToken ? this.attachmentCall(attachment, data) : this.formDataCall(finalData);
}

attachementCall(attachment, data) {
  this.http
    // at first get attachment's token
    .post('/attachments', attachment)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((attachmentToken) => {
        const formData = {
          data,
          attachment: attachmentToken
        };

        this.attachmentToken = attachmentToken;

        // submit form data
        return this.formDataCall(formData);
      }),
    );
}

formDataCall() {
  return this.http.post('/submitformdata', formData);
}
```

Comment: catchError() method is catching errors from '/attachments' service call or from '/submitformdata' service call?

Comment: Since it's piped into `'/attachments'`, I'd say `'/attachments'`

Comment: Ohh, but I need to track '/submitformdata' service error, then I need to pipe it in formDataCall() method?

Comment: Your request was `attachement → formdata`, and if it fails `attachement → void`. Did I misunderstood you ?

Comment: Little bit. I have outside error tracking for '/attachments' which isn't included in this case. Task is to not call one more time '/attachments' service, if 'formdata' service failed.

Comment: First I call '/attachments' service, get token, then call '/formdata', get error. User click one more time Submit button and in this case, not needed to call one more time '/attachments', because I got it's token in previous button click.

Comment: Okay I see, wait I second while I'm editing my answer (again)

Comment: @TomsTumshais I have edited it, try it and tell me what you think

Comment: Looks fine, now I need just to handle attachment's token refreshing, but it's a different task. Thanks!